# If height more than 100px, change position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.pi-img').height() > 100) {
        $(this).css('top' , '30%');
        console.log('yeah');
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** to loop through the `.pi-img` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pi-img').each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > 100) {
            $(this).css('top' , '30%'); 
            console.log('yeah');
        }
    });
});
```